# MultipartFile object is always null

Tags: java, spring-mvc

**What I wanted to do:** When a user uploads a `*.json` file, (actually three, but two other are omitted to test one-file case first) the controller parses JSON and changes value in a database. The file will not be stored to anywhere, but just discarded after being read.

**Controller method:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update/post", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
public String updateP
        (
                Model model,
                @RequestParam(value = "dancer_info", required = false) MultipartFile dancerInfo,
                // if required set to true, it says "Required request part 'dancer_info' is not present".
                HttpServletRequest request
        )
{        

    if (dancerInfo == null)
    {
        model.addAttribute("dancer", "Null");
    }
    else
    {
        String jsonDancerInfo = dancerInfo.toString();
        model.addAttribute("dancer", jsonDancerInfo);
    }

    return "update_complete";
}
```

**Form in `update.html` (using Bootstrap 4):**

```
<form th:action="@{/update/post}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="custom-file">
                        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="dancer_info" name="dancer_info">
                        <label class="custom-file-label" for="dancer_info">dancer_info.json</label>
                    </div>
                </div>                
                <div class="input-group mb-3 justify-content-center align-items-center">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
                </div>
            </form>
```

**`MultipartResolver` bean:**

```
@Bean
public MultipartResolver multipartResolver()
{
    CommonsMultipartResolver mr =  new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    mr.setMaxInMemorySize(102400);
    mr.setMaxUploadSize(102400);
    return mr;
}
```

**Template `update_complete.html`:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>dancer <span th:text="${dancer}"></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

**Result:** `dancer Null`

- I expected something like `dancer dancer_info.json` or something from `MultipartFile.toString()`

**What I tried before:**

- Using `StandardServletMultipartResolver` instead of `CommonsMultipartResolver`: I could not find `setMaxUploadSize()` equivalent of it, so I cannot apply this.
- Using `@RequestBody` instead of `@RequestParam`: same result.
- Renaming `dancer_info` to `file`: same result.

What is missing in my case?

- **Edit**: From @JB Nizet 's comment, I added `name="dancer_info"` in the `<input>` tag but the result was same.

Comment: Your input doesn't have `name="dancer_info"`.

Comment: @JBNizet : I tried that but it still says `dancer Null`...